# Python: searching for a string on a file

Tags: python, search

I'm trying to search for today's date (2017-05-03) on a file populated with several dates. If the date is found on the file, then it returns true and continues the script, if not it ends the execution.

Here's my sample `days.txt` file:

```
2017-05-01
2017-05-03
2017-04-03
```

This is my script:

```
# Function to search the file
def search_string(filename, searchString):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            return searchString in line

# Getting today's date and formatting as Y-m-d
today = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

# Searching the script for the date
if search_string('days.txt', today):
    print "Found the date. Continue script"
else:
    print "Didn't find the date, end execution"
```

However it always returns False, even if the date is present on my txt file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is testing only the first line, so it return True only if the first line contain your string. It should be :

```
def search_string(filename, searchString):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if searchString in line:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: That was quick, thanks for sharing that knowledge and helping me out!

Comment: Always happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You `return` from the search too early.

**FIX**

```
# Function to search the file
def search_string(filename, searchString):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if searchString in line: 
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Had to accept the answer above as it was faster.

Comment: @Luiz No problem.